# Prove multivariable function is surjective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am a little confused on how to prove a multivariable function is surjective(onto).

The function is $f: \mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N$ such that $f(a,b) = a^b$

I tried thinking of a counter example but not sure if that would work here.

Thanks,

Comment: You mean "surjective" not "subjective"

Answer (score 1):

Take $b=1$ and $a$ arbitrary.  That shows any $a$ in $\mathbb N$ is hit by your function.